# Excel use one column as two datasets

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am working with some data in Excel and I would like to create a combined chart, but I am facing some issues as they are slightly different than usual. I have the

```
x-Axis || ID || value
 0.1   || 1  ||   4
 0.3   || 2  ||   6
 0.35  || 1  ||   3
 0.5   || 2  ||   5
 ....
 0.99  || 1  ||   50
  1    || 2  ||   33
  1    || 1  ||   67
```

The X-axis goes from 0 to 1, but I need to show a single line chart with 2 lines, one line for ID 1 and another line for ID 2. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to plot two lines, you need two series. The data for the two series needs to be arranged in two columns. The data for the series does not have to be contiguous. If you use a scatter chart, there can be gaps in the data. Consider this screenshot:

[image]

The formula in D2 is

`=IF($B2=1,$C2,NA())` copied down.

In E2 it is

`=IF($B2=2,$C2,NA())` copied down.

then insert a scatter chart with the values of Column A as the X axis and the values of columns D and E as the Y axis values of the two series.

Comment: This looks promising, will try and I will accept it if works as intended :)